# skspritenode showing white image

Tags: swift, skspritenode

I try to make tower defense game. My question is i added png images.(these two little soldier's image) how i remove white area?

The walking area code is: (and the images added to project with names: 1.png, 2.png, 3.png

```
var char = [SKTexture]();
for i in 1...3 {
    char.append( SKTexture(imageNamed: String(i)) );
}
var runningAction = SKAction.animateWithTextures(char, timePerFrame: 0.18);
self.runAction(SKAction.repeatActionForever(runningAction))
```

[image]

Comment: I'm having the same issue, and if I set a size on the sprite node the image sizes down, but the white box stays the same size. Did you ever figure anything out?

Comment: The png images has white background. I create new image and copy/paste image to new image and save as .png image then add to the Xcode. It worked.. You should check images which has white background or hasn't...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should check `1.png`, `2.png` and `3.png` - they probably have a white instead of transparent background.